# How to extract AdaBoosts outputs that have made the classifiers decision?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, adaboost

I am using AdaBoost in scikit-learn to separate some signal and background data. From my understanding of AdaBoost at the end of each iteration each data item is assigned +1 for signal and -1 for background. The sum of these is then calculated for example a data item that was classified as signal 30 times and background 5 times would have a score of 25. This sum then informs how AdaBoost classifies each data item.

In the following paper "Boosted decision trees as an alternative to artificial neural networks for particle identification", Nuclear instrumentation and methods in physics research, 2005 I found the following graph.

[image: AdaBoost output histogram]

In this graph they call the sum I described above as AdaBoost Ouput. I wish to create a similar graph but am unsure what this output or sum is actually called and how to find this value in scikit-learn. Any help?

Comment: You question isn't entirely clear, and we ask that questions on stack overflow include a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've tried so far so that we can better understand how to help. Based on my reading of your question, I assume you're looking for the "predicted class" from your adaboost classifier

Comment: Hi! My questions is unclear and does not have example code as I am searching for a function and cannot find the name of the output I am searching for, this is the sum I described above. I don't think predicted class is it as I don't want to know what the classifier thinks the class of something is, I want to know the sum of how it has classified each data point in order to make it's classification decision. I hope this helps clarify things a bit!